Which type of the helical and chiral spin texture are these plots?
enter image description here
I have these two plots for the spin texture. Which type of helical and chiral spin texture are they?
Thanks.

Hi Mohammad Mortezaei Nobahari. Welcome to Phys.SE. Are these plots from a reference? Which page?

Hello, No, these are my results and aren't from any reference.
